# Trouble Creating a Web Service

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, httpclient

I have an application to call a web-service to get the PNR status. but I'm newbies for creating a web-service so I have gone through some videos and examples to know how to create and consume a web-service.

I found one question on **stackoverflow**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598485/need-indian-railway-apis-for-making-app-for-pnr-status-train-info-etc and all links provided in this question and I got this : http://pnrapi.alagu.net/ .

**My code is :**

XML : activity_status_pnr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/et_pnr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/h"
        android:maxLength="10" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/pnr_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gstatus" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA code : StatusPNR.java

```
package com.example.infopnr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;  

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;  
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;  

public class StatusPNR extends Activity {  

  String URL = "http://pnrapi.alagu.net/api/v1.0/pnr/UR_PNR_CODE";  
  String result = "";  
  //String deviceId = "xxxxx" ;   
  //final String tag = "Your Logcat tag: ";  

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_pnr);  

      final EditText txtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pnr);  
      txtSearch.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener()
      {  
          public void onClick(View v){txtSearch.setText("");}
      });

      final Button btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pnr_status);  
      btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){  
          public void onClick(View v) {  
              String query = txtSearch.getText().toString();  
              PNRWebService(query);  

          }  
      });  

      } 

  private void PNRWebService(String q){


  }
}
```

I have not created the web-service method yet as I faced some problem here. On some website I read that Apache web-server should be used for get HTTP Clients. But, I am not sure and don't know why is it for?

**My question is:**

1) Is their anything need to installed to get the web-server or our coding is enough to call the web-service without any prior installation of anything?

2) In PNRWebService() method, what are the thing I need to do to get the connection and to call the service with URL? I know I need to establish connection through HTTPClient but after going through many examples and videos I did not get how actually they are doing it?

3) http://pnrapi.alagu.net/ with the reference of this site I am trying to get PNR status? To call this what I need to do, as I don't know what is the URL in this and what further I should do after getting URL as well?

4) I have imported some packages from Apache, I don't know its worthy or not?

PLEASE HELP GUYS IF ANYONE HAS A GOOD KNOWLEDGE, THEN PLEASE LET ME KNOW HOW TO PERFORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. First i suggest you use AsyncTask. You can google it and find out how it is done.

Here's a sample code

```
//Main Class
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String url = "http://pnrapi.alagu.net/api/v1.0/pnr/UR_PNR_CODE";



//Your call to asynctask
 new asyncTask(this).execute(url);

}

//asyncTask class
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    int code;
String codeValue = "";

    public asyncTask(Context cxt) {
        context = cxt;

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        Log.d("in ASyn Task", arg0[0]);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(arg0[0]);//This get your URL
        Log.d("after url in httpget", "after url");


        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
            code = line.getStatusCode();
            codeValue = String.valueOf(code); 
            Log.d("code", codeValue);
            Log.d("Response", "Connected");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("Response 2", "not Connected in exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generatedcatch block
            Log.d("Response 3", e.toString());
        }



        return "Connected !!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        dialog.show();

        // Toast.makeText(asyncTask.this,"Please wait.. !! Uploading data to server",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Alert");
    if (code == 200) {
        alert.setMessage("Connection to host established !! ")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });

    }

    else {
        alert.setMessage("Error Connecting to server. Try Again")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });
    }

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Check if the code you get is 200.. if yes you are able to  establish a connection with the web service.(done in onPostExecute in the above code)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Pal ! I have implemented it but I want to ask that I want to call the ansynTask on click of the button and when i am creating it like this : final Button btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pnr_status);  
      btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){  
          public void onClick(View v) {  
           
           new asyncTask(this).execute(URL); 
                
          }  
      });

Comment: It is showing error : The constructor StatusPNR.asyncTask(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined....here i can't call constructor on on-clickListener event as context value is there. Right?

Comment: I want to no that is it possible to call a asyncTask on OnClick Event and if not then how the program will come to know that from where they need to fetch the PNR and after clicking where they need to start the process ? I am bit confuse.

Comment: i just tried with a button its working mOkbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                              
                                    new asyncTask(myactivity.this).execute(url);
                                    
                                    }
                        } 
                  }
            });
Thats a sample

Comment: I think its something to do with your code.. Please check what i have posted and give a try

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to know is the webservice you are trying to access is **Restful** Webservice.

Second thing, response of the  webservice is in **json** format.(u can use gson library here to parse data)

Third, You'll need to run a background process or use **AsyncTask** to perform your network transaction on a background thread.You cannot perform network IO on the UI thread on Honeycombe or later version

several tutorials are available.. just google it..

Check this link :
[Android, Web Services, AsyncTask please help a noob/make sure im starting right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625062/android-web-services-asynctask-please-help-a-noob-make-sure-im-starting-right)

if you still have doubt post it..